# Subcategory wordpress slider css

Tags: css, wordpress

Problem is with the sub category slider in shop for desktop view and per single time 5 sub categories are shown and when you cliclkk on next arrow it just moves one sub category ahead rather than moving 5 ahead and if you would go to customise and click on next in the sub category slider it moves 5 ahead, please help with a css code or something that i can fix this issue so that in shop it can move 5 ahaead rather than 1
https://www.veed.io/view/e4c5f64b-94f6-4cc1-bffa-29f31650fee2/showcase?sharingWidget=true
heres the video with the issue….

The page I need help with: https://executiverugs.com/shop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, theme developers did a basic mistake here and that's why this kind of behavior is coming.

Let me explain to you what is going wrong here and why you have different behavior in the customizer preview and live preview.

so if you'll check this theme js file https://executiverugs.com/wp-content/themes/funio/js/functions.js and search for `slidesToScroll:$element.data("slidestoscroll")`

you'll see `slidesToScroll` has a condition where it checks if `data-slidestoscroll` is available or not, if available then it takes the value from `data-columns` and set it to `slidesToScroll` if `data-slidestoscroll` is not available then it will set value as `1`

So if You'll check your page source and check the `data-slidestoscroll` in div with class `woocommerce-product-subcategories` you'll see `data-slidestoscroll` is missing but `data-columns="5"` is available.
but developers are checking for `data-slidestoscroll` should exist then they will set the value from `data-columns`, so the condition is failing and `slidesToScroll` is getting value `1`

#### Why Customizer has 5 `slidesToScroll`?

In the slick slider, the `responsive` option `breakpoint: 1441` is defined, which defines the `max-width:1441`, and applies certain rules. so for that breakpoint `data-columns1440` or `data-columns` value is conditionally being applied in your case `data-columns` is being used since it's available on your page source.

So when you view the page in the customizer preview, the customizer sidebar on left takes some space so the page viewports are less than `1441px` and in that case, the `responsive` breakpoint rule is taking over.

#### What is the solution?

1. You should contact the theme author/developers and raise an issue about it. so that they can review and provide a solution/fix in the next release.
2. If you know how to edit files using FTP then you need to edit this file `/wp-content/themes/funio/js/functions.js` but take a file backup first. then search for `slidesToScroll:$element.data("slidestoscroll")` then replace it with `slidesToScroll:$element.data("columns")` and save and upload the changes.